# Other way to connect to ldap besides ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-mint, ldap

I have been following some tutorials on installing the client and connecting to the LDAP server and they all say its via ssh.

Is there another way besides ssh to connect to the LDAP server?

Answer (score 1):

An example with `ldapsearch` command line tool:

```
ldapsearch -b "dc=foobar,dc=fr" -D "cn=Manager,dc=foobar,dc=fr" -w ldap
```

It comes with `openldap` package.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is a protocol,  transmitted described in terms of [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) and transmitted using [BER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_encoding_rules#BER_encoding). It has nothing whatsoever to do with "ssh". LDAP clients connect using the protocol, which is described in RFC4511. Clients may:

- connect on a non-secure connection
- connect on a non-secure connection and promote the connection to a secure connection using the StartTLS extended operation
- connect using SSL (not ssh), in this case the connection is secure right away

As noted, the legacy OpenLDAP distribution includes the `ldapsearch` command. Many programming languages include an API for LDAP, most notably [Java](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/).

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)
- [LDAP: The Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511)